# how to get index of value in dictionary in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing, nsarray, nsdictionary

an array like this:

> ```
>     <array>
>       <dict>
>         <key>Place</key>
>         <string>A</string>
>         <key>Name</key>
>         <string>B</string>
>         <key>Object</key>
>         <string>C</string>
>       </dict>
>       <dict>
>         <key>Place</key>
>         <string>D</string>
>         <key>Name</key>
>         <string>E</string>
>         <key>Object</key>
>         <string>F</string>
>       </dict>
>       <dict>
>         <key>Place</key>
>         <string>X</string>
>         <key>Name</key>
>         <string>Y</string>
>         <key>Object</key>
>         <string>Z</string>
>       </dict>
>       <dict>
>         <key>Place</key>
>         <string>S</string>
>         <key>Name</key>
>         <string>T</string>
>         <key>Object</key>
>         <string>U</string>
>       </dict>
>       ...
>     </array>
> ```

// for some reason, I simplified levels of this sample by removing original top level array. Now they look like an array composed of some dictionaries.

for instance, can got any value via `[[objectArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Place"]`, if like X,

then, in another place still in same `.m`, need to **ONLY** leverage X to reversely get what's index of the dictionary where X is. Because in this place, only the objectArray is able to be accessed.

What's right method that's supposed to do?

Comment: Your array is two layers deep but you're only showing one level of indexing.

Answer (score 8):

Use KVC again!

3 lines when you have the array :D

## short

```
NSArray *arrayWithDicts = @[d1,d2,d3,d4];//your array!

NSArray *arrayWithPlaces = [arrayWithDicts valueForKey:@"Place"];
NSUInteger index = [arrayWithPlaces indexOfObject:@"cologne"];
NSDictionary *dict = index != NSNotFound ? arrayWithDicts[index] : nil;
```

## full example

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //build demo array
        NSDictionary *d1 = @{@"Place": @"clackson"};
        NSDictionary *d2 = @{@"Place": @"berlin"};
        NSDictionary *d3 = @{@"Place": @"cologne"};
        NSDictionary *d4 = @{@"Place": @"mclean"};
        NSArray *arrayWithDicts = @[d1,d2,d3,d4];

        //get all places
        NSArray *arrayWithPlaces = [arrayWithDicts valueForKey:@"Place"];
        assert(arrayWithDicts.count == arrayWithPlaces.count);

        //find place and get dict
        NSUInteger index = [arrayWithPlaces indexOfObject:@"cologne"];
        NSDictionary *dict = index != NSNotFound ? arrayWithDicts[index] : nil;

        NSLog(@"%@", dict);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Didn't know you could access values this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the outer array, and in that loop you need to loop over the inner array, looking for the dictionary whose value for `@"Place"` is `X`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
@implementation NSArray (StackOverflow)

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathOfDictionaryWithPlace:(NSString *)place {
    // I can't refer directly to an array inside a block, so I have to add an extra variable.
    NSUInteger indexStorage[2];
    NSUInteger *indexes = indexStorage;

    indexes[0] = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray *subarray = obj;
        indexes[1] = [subarray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = obj;
            return [place isEqualToString:dictionary[@"Place"]];
        }];
        return indexes[1] != NSNotFound;
    }];

    if (indexes[0] == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:2];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your detail codes that seems can fix my question. But....it looks very concise, as well as complicated to me especially those ternary operators. If I could understand your codes, I would not propose this question... as I'm new to app dev...:) I simplified sample codes to an one level array composed of some dictionaries. Other conditions stay as they are. Looking forward to your updated codes in a normal way that newbie could understand, like me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @iOS.dev: requesting simpler codes instead of working yourself through this not very complex code will not help to advance to the next level.

Comment: @ios.dev consider my kvc-based answer then. it has less code ;)

Comment: @iOS.dev Yeah, I'm totally late to the game, but you should accept Daij-Djan's answer (not this one). It works perfectly.